# Optimal procedure to rename files in a linux directory

Tags: regex, linux, file-rename

This question pertains to renaming files in a directory on a Linux system wherein the affected files appear in this general format:

```
index.html?p=155
index.html?page_id=10
index.html?author=2&paged=5
index.html?feed=rss2&tag=search-engine
index.html?tag=social-media
```

Might there be a shell level "rename" command that I can use to replace the question marks (?) with an underscore (_) in each file within a directory?

Thank you in advance for any advice or information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the [`rename`](/a/17538408/) command myself, though sometimes a roll-your-own [`for`](/a/17538385/) loop can be more targeted.

Note: `rename` takes a [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) expression as the argument to change and filenames as the last argument. The proper call to use would be:

```
rename 's/\?/_/' index*
```

because the `?` indicates 0 or 1 of a preceding character when not `\` escaped.

This is also easier to toss into a `find` command which can operate recursively, etc:

```
find . -name index.html* -exec rename 's/\?/_/' {} +
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an *excellent* response that worked the moment I tried it! More importantly, thank you for providing some additional information that I have noted so that I can continue to learn more about how to use the rename function more effectively in the future. Thanks again, I really (really!) appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome :) I need to read more myself about `find` though, there is more under those covers...

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in index.html\?*; do
  new=${file/\?/_} # Substitute underscore for ?
  mv "$file" "$new" # Rename the file
done
```

See the Parameter Expansion section of the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for information on the substitution syntax used.

Comment: Hi! I'm going to store this code and potentially use it in the future. The solution that utilized the rename command proved to be the short-term solution that I was seeking, but what you provided appears to have some excellent long-term value. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rename command.

```
rename '?' '_' *
```

The first parameter is the expression you want to replace, the second argument is the string to replace the first parameter with, and the final option is the selection of files to apply it to ( all in the current directory, in this case )

See the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rename.html) for more details.http://ss64.com/bash/rename.html